# C to C++ converter

Tags: c++, c

Some of the `C` code do not compile with `C++` compiler if compiled as `C++` files, due to the stricter type safety of `C++`. Is there any tool which takes the `C` code and generates a valid `C++` code out of it. In other words, it adds to the `C` code what is required to make that code compile with a `C++` compiler.

Note that I know that C and C++ code can be linked, but here I'm specifically talking about taking a C code and compiling it with a C++ compiler treating them as C++ code files.

Comment: David, And that tool doesn't have any time or stamina to do it :(!

Comment: the type safety system is there to prevent you from making writing bugs.  Isn't systematically examining the spots where the c++ compiler complains and fixing them better than leaving potential bugs in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try compiling with additional flags to make it less strict and/or a different compiler.

Edit #1: I can't add comments. I'm just throwing around ideas, I haven't first-hand executed these. After a bit of digging around, you might be SOL depending on if the C code is written in part of the set that isn't a subset of C++.

If it's just non-ansi C standard issues, you might be able to finagle it. If you're using gcc, maybe try using Microsoft Visual C++ or OpenWatcom.

As for the flags, I thought you could do leniency, but I could be wrong. The flags will depend on the compiler, I think I've used -std=isoC99, -compat, -feat=features.

Answer (score 3):

Simply place your C code in a separated .c file, within your project, and you should be able to compile it as C. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I would have done if I could do so, but I need to modify that code and need to put C++ constructs into it, so separating it in separate C files is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The languages are sufficiently different that any attempt to directly convert is doomed to failure. You'd have to go through an intermediate artificial language where the C was already essentially compiled for it to be feasible, and at that point, the resulting C++ will be so ugly you would not want to see it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to consider this as being a mix of C and C++ code and use compiler directives in your relevant header files as follows:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"
#endif
```

You can reference C++ FAQ-Lite's "[How to mix C and C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)" for a more thorough discussion of the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if such a tool exists.
Never tried this since I never had the need, but: 
You can try compiling the C code as a lib. Maybe, if you are lucky, just the header files of your C code are valid C++. Include those headers in your C++, and link to the lib.

Again, never tried this, do not know if it will work. Just an idea.